# Kapt options are not recognized by any processor

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-room, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I can't figure out why the kotlin annotation processor cannot resolve these arguments.

Relevant parts of my build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        kapt {
            arguments {
                arg("room.incremental", "true")
                arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:${Versions.room_version}") // room_version = "2.2.4"
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:${Versions.room_version}")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:${Versions.room_version}")
}
```

The exact warning I get is

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[room.schemaLocation, kapt.kotlin.generated, room.incremental]'
The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[room.schemaLocation, kapt.kotlin.generated, room.incremental]'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your code does not use any of your `Annotation processor's` annotation then the kapt task will be skipped and no annotation processor will be invoked hence, options you passed will be ignored since no **invoked** annotation processor (if any) is interested in them.

Comment: i am using the same with @Rishabh Kohli code and i am using room in my code with dagger hilt and i am getting the same warning and an extra one which is 
 "class file for androidx.room.RoomDatabase not found"

Answer (score 2):

Seems my problem was that I was trying to build the app right after setting up gradle, without actually implementing room annotations in the app.
Once I did that, the warning went away.

I figure that the annotation processor does not get engaged at all till there are relevant annotations.